# Rename Won't Rename Files Despite Clearly Detecting Them

Tags: bash, terminal, rename

It looks like rename is detecting the files, but it states that it isn't.

```
user@DESKTOP:/mnt/f/PS2/PS2 Upload$ rename 's/(.*)//' *.iso
Can't rename Bully (USA).iso : No such file or directory
Can't rename Grand Theft Auto - San Andreas (USA) (v3.00).iso : No such file or directory
Can't rename Gran Turismo 4 (Europe, Australia) (En,Fr,De,Es,It).iso : No such file or directory
Can't rename Metal Gear Solid 3 - Snake Eater (USA).iso : No such file or directory
Can't rename Mortal Kombat - Armageddon - Premium Edition (USA).iso : No such file or directory
Can't rename Mortal Kombat - Deadly Alliance (USA).iso : No such file or directory
Can't rename Mortal Kombat - Deception (USA).iso : No such file or directory
Can't rename Mortal Kombat - Shaolin Monks (USA).iso : No such file or directory
Can't rename Ratchet & Clank - Going Commando (USA).iso : No such file or directory
Can't rename Ratchet & Clank - Up Your Arsenal (USA) (En,Fr,Es).iso : No such file or directory
Can't rename Ratchet & Clank (USA) (En,Fr,De,Es,It).iso : No such file or directory
Can't rename Red Dead Revolver (USA).iso : No such file or directory
Can't rename Shadow of the Colossus (USA).iso : No such file or directory
Can't rename Tekken 5 (USA).iso : No such file or directory
```

Comment: You can't rename files to the empty string. `rename` is not a standard command; this could also simply be a bug in whichever version you are running. The mount path looks vaguely like you are trying to operate on a Windows file system, with no indication whether your OS supports writing to that particular filesystem type. Stack Overflow is for _programming_ questions, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Rename was trying to rename files to the empty string. The parenthesis need to be escaped.

```
rename 's/\(.*\)//' *.iso
```